# Why the probability $P(X>Y)$ is the same as $P(\log X > \log Y)$?

Tags: probability

Why the probability $P(X>Y)$ is the same as $P(\log X > \log Y)$? Assuming $X,Y$ are integer-valued random variables..

Thanks

Comment: The logarithm is an increasing function.

Comment: So $x>y$ if and only if $\ln(x)>\ln(y)$.

Comment: I edited and wrote $X,Y$ integer-valued random variables. If $x,y$ are just integers it doesn't make sense to take a probability of that, does it?

Comment: You need both of $X,Y \gt 0$ for this implication to make sense.  Integer or not does not matter

Answer (score 7):

Because the two sets of which you are calculating the probability are the same.

$$\{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) > Y(\omega)\} = \{\omega \in \Omega: \log X(\omega) >\log  Y(\omega)\} $$

which is true since $\log$ is an increasing function.

Now since if $A=B \implies P(A) = P(B)$ (duh!) , then

$$P(X > Y) = P(\log X > \log Y)$$

Note that we only need $X,Y$ to be positive random variable for this to work, not necessarily natural

Answer (score 0):

we have 
$$x>y$$
Taking log both sides.. 
$$\log x>\log y$$
$$P(x>y)=P(\log x>\log y)$$
because $(x,y)$ belong to the same set of values.